# iOS Simulator no longer connects to networked midi after upgrade to xcode 4.3.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, midi, simulator

I built an application using the PGMIDI (https://github.com/petegoodliffe/PGMidi). As soon as I updated xcode to 4.3.2 with the iOS 5.1 SDK, the simulator no longer found the networked midi connection (see http://syntheticbits.com/blog/?p=878). I tried this with the PGMIDI sandbox app and it also no longer worked. Networked midi connections still work when the app is deployed on a device, however.

I then upgraded to 4.3.2 on my laptop as well and the same thing occurred. I've spoke with another developer who is working on a similar project whether his broke when upgrading, but he had no issues. I tried reinstalling xcode and I tried using the ios 5.0 simulator, but no luck. I also tried resetting my modem and router.

On my school's network I noticed my device (iPhone 4GS) specifically was blocked from connecting to networked midi, but other devices were picked up and the simulator worked. I wonder if this is network specific. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change base sdk in project settings and then rebuild your app.